# What part of the C spec, if any, specifies that C standard library input functions leave the latter part of a buffer unchanged?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Example: Assume a file is opened successfully in text mode, line ending translations are not an issue and the file contains `"12345\n"` and it is read **successfully** using one of 3 functions,

```
int main(void) {
  char *Filename = "c:\\tmp\\text.txt";
  FILE *stream = fopen(Filename, "w");
  assert(stream);
  fputs("12345\n", stream);
  fclose(stream);

  stream = fopen(Filename, "r");
  assert(stream);
  char buf[8];

  rewind(stream);
  memset(buf, 'x', sizeof buf);
  size_t sz = fread(buf, 1, sizeof buf, stream);
  // Is buf[6], buf[7] specified to remain unchanged as `x'?
  printf("<%.6s> %c %c\n", buf, buf[6], buf[7]);
  assert(sz == 6);

  rewind(stream);
  memset(buf, 'y', sizeof buf);
  fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stream);
  // Is buf[7] specified to remain unchanged as `y'?
  printf("<%s> %d %c\n", buf, buf[6], buf[7]);
  assert(strlen(buf) == 6);

  rewind(stream);
  memset(buf, 'z', sizeof buf);
  fscanf(stream, "%7[^\n]", buf);
  // Is buf[6], buf[7] specified remain unchanged as `z'?
  printf("<%s> %c %c\n", buf, buf[6], buf[7]);
  assert(strlen(buf) == 5);

  fclose(stream);
  return 0;
}
```

Sample output

```
<12345
> x x
<12345
> 0 y
<12345> z z
```

> What *specifies*, directly or indirectly, that the last part of `buf` remains unaltered?
>   Perhaps it is just common *unspecified* practice.

---

Side data: On read error, the buffer contents are undefined - but this is about an error-less read.

I rarely see a need to know the stability of the remnant part of the buffer and by experimentation, I have seen no change. I read the idea of using `memset(buf, '\n', sizeof buf);` prior to `fgets()` to help detect possible null characters and that first made me first think of the specificity.

Comment: You are using a M$ system, which removes the '\r' silently. maybe try open in "rb" mode ?

Comment: @wildplasser This is not an end-of-line conversion issue.  Change `"12345\n"` to `"123456"` if needed.

Comment: The standard says that both `fgets` and `fread` operate as though they were implemented by successive calls to `fgetc`. In the case of `fgets`, at least, it also says that no additional characters are read after an end-of-file (or newline). Isn't that sufficient?

Comment: Since each of the three examples specifies how much buffer is available, surely the library functions are at liberty to use any location in the buffer they choose to?

Comment: @rici I have not found "standard says that both fgets and fread operate as though they were implemented by successive calls to fgetc".   Do you have a citation?

Comment: @WeatherVane "library functions are at liberty to use any location in the buffer they choose to?" maybe, maybe not.  I would _think_ a function could do so unless specified against it.

Comment: @chux: for fread, that is what the description says: each object is read with size calls to fgetc. For fgets, it's in the overview.

Comment: Looking at the third example `fscanf(stream, "%7[^\n]", buf);` and comparing it with the similar but unspecified buffer size `fscanf(stream, "%[^\n]", buf);` would the library function be at liberty to write anything beyond the space required in that second case? If so *how far beyond*? If not, why would it when the buffer size is specified?

Comment: ... 7.21.3 para 11 "The byte input functions read characters from the stream as if by successive calls to the fgetc function."

Comment: @WeatherVane Note that `7` is the width specifier, not a buffer size - but similar effect.  You idea _is_ insightful.  Hmmm.

Comment: @rice [Very good](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41539279/what-part-of-the-c-spec-if-any-specifies-that-c-standard-library-input-functio?noredirect=1#comment70284306_41539279)  Hmm  with `§7.21.1  5 "The byte input/output functions  ...fgets,... fread, ... fscanf..." does seem to tie it up nicely.  Write the answer if you like.  If you or someone else does not after a day or 2 I'll write one.

Comment: This case does not yet appear closed to me: "...as if by successive calls to the **fgetc** function." `fgetc()` returns a character in the form of an `int`, while `fgets()` stores a character, in the form of a `char`, in a buffer, and returns a pointer. Note that `fgetc()` can return `EOF`, but `fgets()` can not necessarily store `EOF` in the buffer. The Standard seems to specify how characters are retrieved from a file, but not how they are stored in the buffer. The question seems to ask about the manner in which this storage may be legally implemented.

Comment: @DavidBowling Yes I have had 2nd thoughts too - sometimes best to mull this over.

Comment: @DavidBowling: `EOF` is not a character. It is a value returned by `fgetc` to indicate that no character is available. Not coincidentally, it cannot be confused with a character returned by `fgetc`. (See § 7.21.7.1 para 3: "… if the stream is at end-of-file… the `fgetc` function returns `EOF`. **Otherwise**, the `fgetc` function returns the next character." and §7.21.1 para 3: `EOF` is a negative integer which "is returned by several functions to indicate end-of-file, that is, no more input from a
stream".)

Comment: @rici-- Yes, perhaps my language was a bit loose here. The point was that we can't even say that the result of a call to `fgets()` must look like the result of successive calls to `fgetc()` without needing some additional interpretation. I agree that it seems common-sense that the buffer beyond the `NUL` should be unmodified, but I still don't see where the Standard says that `fgets()` can't tinker with the buffer before storing characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my understanding, it is guaranteed that these three calls will not modify `buf` beyond the last character read plus a NUL character in the case of `fgets` and `fscanf`.

The most relevant requirement from the standard is in §7.21.3 paragraph 11:

> The byte input functions read characters from the stream as if by successive calls to the `fgetc` function.

("byte input functions" is defined at §7.21.1 paragraph 5, and includes fgetc, fgets, fprintf, fputc, fputs, fread, fscanf, fwrite, getc, getchar, printf, putc, putchar, puts, scanf,
ungetc, vfprintf, vfscanf, vprintf, and vscanf.)

That explains how data is read, but it is not 100% precise about how it is handled once it has been read. For that, it is necessary to look at individual function definitions (and possibly to apply some common sense).

#### fgets

For `fgets`, we read that (§7.21.7.2 paragraph 2):

> No additional characters are read after a new-line character (which is retained) or after end-of-file.

That seems crystal clear to me.

#### fscanf

For `fscanf`, we need to refer to the description of the `s` conversion specifier (§7.21.6.2 paragraph 12) which laconically states that it matches:

> a sequence of non-white-space characters

However, we also have §7.21.6.2 paragraph 9, which describes the work leading up to the application of the conversion specifier:

> An input item is read from the stream… An input item is defined as the longest sequence of input characters which does not exceed any specified field width and which is, or is a prefix of, a matching input sequence. The first character, if any, after the input item remains unread.

So the read must terminate at the first white-space character or the end of the input. Once the read terminates, a null character is appended, but no more reading is done (for this conversion specifier).

#### fread

The `fread` function is specified at §7.21.8.1, which states (in paragraph 2):

> The `fread` function reads, into the array pointed to by `ptr`, up to `nmemb` elements whose size is specified by `size`, from the stream pointed to by stream. For each object, `size` calls are made to the `fgetc` function and the results stored, in the order read…

This doesn't quite state that the read stops early if an error or end-of-file is returned by `fgetc`, but paragraph 3 states that:

> The `fread` function returns the number of elements successfully read, which may be less than `nmemb` if a read error or end-of-file is encountered.

English is slightly ambiguous here: the natural interpretation is that the return value may be less than `nmemb`, which will happen if the read was terminated prematurely. A hostile reading of that sentence might be that a read error or end-of-file *may result* in a premature termination (as opposed to *will result*...), but (speaking as a native English speaker), I don't believe that is an accurate understanding of the intent of the sentence. In any case, common sense dictates that the natural interpretation is the one intended.

It's worth noting in this case that if `size` is not 1, a partial read which terminates in mid-object may overwrite the entire object. The code in the original question has `size` specified as 1, so this exception is not directly relevant, but had the function call been

```
size_t sz = fread(buf, sizeof buf, 1, stream); /* DON'T COPY THIS CODE */
```

(which you sometimes see, although I personally discourage its use), then it is conformant (although IMHO unlikely) for the `fread` to modify the entire buffer even if only a single byte is available.

Comment: Who highly discourages the code with `1` as the number of objects, and why do they discourage it?  It's a perfectly useful way of calling `fread()` in my book.  It tells you how many complete objects were read.  If you're worried about EOF or an error, then it is legitimate to use `feof()` or `ferror()` to detect problems.  The alternative (using `size_t sz = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), stream);` doesn't help for most purposes.  You have to check `sz != sizeof(buf)` instead of `sz != 1` to detect problems.  No big deal, but in the case where you've got up to 20 objects, you have to work harder.

Comment: I agree with most of the rest of your answer.  I don't see the 'hostile reading' as having any validity.  The only time it will be less than `nmemb` is if a read error or EOF occurs — the 'number of elements successfully read' precludes your attempted 'hostile reading' IMO.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Since I can't off-hand find a luminary who discourages that usage, I edited to indicate that *I* discourage the use, because you can't tell how many bytes were read and the standard doesn't require *any* of the contents of the buffer to correspond to the input. Aside from code-golfing, I don't see the test `sz != sizeof buf` as being problematic. Obviously, I agree with your assessment of the meaning of 7.21.8.1/3 but I have been asked about it more than once by non-native speakers, so I'm aware that the other interpretation exists in the wild.

Comment: I think we're more in agreement than disagreement, despite any nitpicking about to occur.  Knowing how many bytes were read is no help if an error occurs; the state of the object that the read failed on is indeterminate and the position of the read pointer is indeterminate too.  If you were actually reading into an array of characters (bytes), then you have some knowledge, but if you're reading structures, you know how many were read successfully and nothing about the state of the structure that it failed on. Since `fread()` is often used for reading POD structures, this is important.

Comment: Using not-`1` as the second argument would typically be used when you want to read a certain number of fixed-size records, and discard any partial record along with the information about how partial it was. I'd hazard a guess that robust code would rarely do this (preferring at least to be able to report on what went wrong if a partial record was found)

Comment: 'Tis interesting that §7.21.8.1 ¶3 can be or has been misinterpreted.  It amounts to a failure to understand fairly plain English.  Maybe it should be mentioned to the standards committee to see if there is anything they think can and should be done about it.  I think there are more important things for them to worry about, so I don't hold out much hope, but I do think that the 'hostile reading' is clearly not the intended reading.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Turns out that P.J. Plauger makes a similar recommendation in "The Standard C Library" (1991): "As a rule, you are better off calling the function as fread(buf, I, size * n, stream) instead of fread(buf, size, n, stream)", citing the same reason ("you cannot determine whether the
function also read up to size - 1 additional characters beyond what it
reports"). That's probably where the prejudice entered my brain, but I'll leave it in first person now that I've edited it.

Comment: Good book to quote (albeit on the ancient side now — it was for the C90 standard; still a very good book, though).  I guess my main question is "what are you going to do with the information about the number of bytes read that weren't part of a complete structure?"  You don't know where the read position is (that's indeterminate).  There's not clearly anything you could do other than seek to the position one byte beyond the end of the last complete structure and try again, to see whether some other process has finished writing the rest of the structure now, or something along those lines.

Comment: @jonathanleffler: i'd log the the information in an error message. ("Expected %zu bytes but eof encountered after %zu bytes\n.") When you're troubleshooting, little bits of information like this are sometimes invaluable.") But I don't believe the read position is indeterminate after EOF. The standard says it is indeterminate after an error, and EOF is not an error. If EOF is encountered, the read position is where the EOF was encountered, which does not mean it will be re-encountered at the same place.

Comment: IMO, the "successive"  calls is the salient point:  The functions should functionally _act_ as if one-at-a-time calls are made to `fgetc()`.  Together with [@Weather Vane ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41539279/what-part-of-the-c-spec-if-any-specifies-that-c-standard-library-input-functio#comment70284285_41539279) leave no doubt that a compliant function must not write in the latter portion of the buffer.